# Model Error using Mongoose Pagination Package

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use the [mongoose-pagination](https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/mongoose-paginate) package and tried to follow the documentation provided, but it doesn't appear to be working with my model. I am getting this error message:

```
/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/app/models/blogModel.js:16
BlogPostSchema.paginate({}, 2, 10, function(error, pageCount, paginatedResults
               ^
TypeError: Object #<Schema> has no method 'paginate'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/app/models/blogModel.js:16:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/blog/server.js:18:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

And i'm not sure why I am receiving this error because the plugin is supposed to allow for the paginate method.

blogModel.js:

```
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');
var Schema      = mongoose.Schema;
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');



var BlogPostSchema  = new Schema({
        title: String,
        author: String,
        content: String,
        date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

BlogPostSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

BlogPostSchema.paginate({}, 2, 10, function(error, pageCount, paginatedResults, itemCount) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Pages:', pageCount);
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blogpost', BlogPostSchema);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling this wrong. The `.paginate()` method is instantiated on the model. So you set up the plugin on the schema and then make calls from your model instance. In simplified form:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var blogPostSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  author: String,
  content: String,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

blogPostSchema.plugin( mongoosePaginate );

var Blogpost = mongoose.model( "Blogpost", blogPostSchema );

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test')

Blogpost.paginate({}, 2, 10, function(err,pageCount, results, count) {

  // do something with results

})
```

Comment: Thanx @ Neil, this answer really helped.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the selected answer that in the context of a more complex example, one should beware of Schema Caching: My new Model was created using the same name as an existing Model that was not augmented with the pagniate function.

When I was creating the Model using the Schema, I was getting the old version (cached) instead of the new one (the one with paginate).

In short: use different names for different Models!

Hope this help someone!